# What is meant by stream buffering?

Tags: c, stream, buffer

I had started learning C programming, so I'm a beginner, while learning about standard streams of text, I came up with the lines "stdout" stream is buffered while "stderr" stream is not buffered, but I am not able to make sense with this lines.

I already have read about "buffer" on this forum and I like candy analogy, but I am not able to figure out what is meant when one says: "*This stream is buffered and the other one is not.*" What is the effect?

What is the difference?

**Update:** Does it affect the speed of processing?

Comment: Think of `stdout` as a line of shipping *trucks*. You start packing boxes into the lead truck. You send it out when the truck is full *or* when someone blows a horn and says "Ship It!". The truck leave and the next one pulls up to the loading dock where the process continues. Now think of `stderr` as a line of bicycles, each with a rack that can hold *one* box. Each time you throw a box out to be shipped, the rider takes it, and *immediately* leaves (since that can only take one). That pretty much sums it up. And yes, as you can imagine, a thousand bikes is far less efficient than ten trucks.

Comment: @WhozCraig, make than an answer and I'll upvote it. Nice analogy.

Comment: @WhozCraig That's a very apt and helpful analogy, especially `And yes, as you can imagine, a thousand bikes is far less efficient than ten trucks.` This comment deserves to be in an answer :)

Comment: @ajay I actually liked (and up-ticked) both yours and Paul's answers. I particularly liked the summary descriptions of the three buffer methods for gcc in your answer and the brevity of Paul's. My comment was more to try and detach code from concept, and as I wasn't clear that was what the OP was looking for, felt it appropriate here instead of down there. Regardless, thanks for the props!

Answer (score 11):

Buffer is a block of memory which belongs to a stream and is used to hold stream data temporarily. When the first I/O operation occurs on a file, `malloc` is called and a buffer is obtained. Characters that are written to a stream are normally accumulated in the buffer (before being transmitted to the file in chunks), instead of appearing as soon as they are output by the application program. Similarly, streams retrieve input from the host environment in blocks rather than on a character-by-character basis. This is done to increase efficiency, as file and console I/O is slow in comparison to memory operations.

GCC provides three types of buffering - unbuffered, block buffered, and line buffered. Unbuffered means that characters appear on the destination file as soon as written (for an output stream), or input is read from a file on a character-by-character basis instead of reading in blocks (for input streams). Block buffered means that characters are saved up in the buffer and written or read as a block. Line buffered means that characters are saved up only till a newline is written into or read from the buffer.
`stdin` and `stdout` are block buffered if and only if they can be determined not to refer to an interactive device else they are line buffered (this is true of any stream). `stderr` is always unbuffered by default.

The standard library provides functions to alter the default behaviour of streams. You can use `fflush` to force the data out of the output stream buffer (`fflush` is undefined for input streams). You can make the stream unbuffered using the `setbuf` function.

Answer (score 3):

Buffering is collecting up many elements before writing them, or reading many elements at once before processing them. Lots of information out there on the Internet, for example, [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Stream-Buffering.html#Stream-Buffering)

and other SO questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19898577/c-sharp-how-using-buffered-stream-is-different-than-reading-same-number-of-byt)

EDIT in response to the question update: And yes, it's done for performance reasons. Writing and reading from disks etc will in any case write or read a 'block' of some sort for most devices, and there's a fair overhead in doing so. So batching these operations up can make for a dramatic performance difference

Comment: I'm happy you added that edit! It is the best answer to my question! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A program writing to buffered output can perform the output in the time it takes to write to the buffer which is typically very fast, independent of the speed of the output device which may be slow.

With buffered output the information is queues and a separate process deals with the output rendering.

With unbuffered output, the data is written directly to the output device, so runs at the speed on the device.  This is important for error output because if the output were buffered it would be possible for the process to fail before the buffered output has made it to the display - so the program might terminate with no diagnostic output.