# C++ I Want to write two strings into pipe with a small delay between

Tags: c++, pipe, fork

I want to send string "one" to the pipe then wait a second and send string "two" to the pipe. Afterwards it should get printed to the console.
If I run the Program now it waits one second and then it prints both strings instead of print "one" wait a second and print the other one.

How can I achieve my goal=

Code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Read characters from the pipe and echo them to stdout. */

void
read_from_pipe (int file)
{
    FILE *stream;
    int c;
    stream = fdopen (file, "r");
    while ((c = fgetc (stream)) != EOF)
        putchar (c);
    fclose (stream);
}

/* Write some random text to the pipe. */

void
write_to_pipe (int file)
{
    FILE *stream;
    stream = fdopen (file, "w");
    fprintf (stream, "one\n");
    sleep(1);
    fprintf (stream, "two\n");
    fclose (stream);
}

int
main (void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int mypipe[2];

    /* Create the pipe. */
    if (pipe (mypipe))
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Pipe failed.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Create the child process. */
    pid = fork ();
    if (pid == (pid_t) 0)
    {
        /* This is the child process.
           Close other end first. */
        close (mypipe[1]);
        read_from_pipe (mypipe[0]);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    else if (pid < (pid_t) 0)
    {
        /* The fork failed. */
        fprintf (stderr, "Fork failed.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
    {
        /* This is the parent process.
           Close other end first. */
        close (mypipe[0]);
        write_to_pipe (mypipe[1]);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you sleep a longer time?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure for your platform/compiler but, generally, the `Sleep()` function takes its argument in ***milliseconds*** - try `Sleep(1000)`.

Comment: You could try to open and close the stream twice

Comment: @Adrian no `sleep` takes seconds as argument: https://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep

Comment: @RoQuOTriX I said I wasn't sure … coming from a Windows background, you see (hence capital S in Sleep).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is caused by buffering. For more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23299046/4396133

Use the `fflush()` to write data to stream immediately as shown in below code:

```
void
write_to_pipe (int file)
{
    FILE *stream;
    stream = fdopen (file, "w");
    fprintf (stream, "one\n");
    fflush(stream);
    sleep(1);
    fprintf (stream, "two\n");
    fflush(stream);
    fclose (stream);
}
```

Comment: I would like to put this code into a for loop and write an integer to the pipe. How can I do this? Because when I try its not working because there is no fprintf method where I can write an int.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "there is no fprintf method where I can write an int". Better ask a new question with the code you have tried and we will try to help.