# std::this_thread::sleep_for() freezing the program

Tags: c++

I am making a loading type function so what I wanted to do was to halt my program for a few seconds and then resume the execution inside a loop to make it look like a loading process. Looking up on web I found that I can use `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` to achieve this (I am doing this on linux). The problem I am facing is that I am unable to make it work with `\r` or any other way to overwrite the last outputted percentage as the program freezes as soon as I do it, however it works perfectly with `\n` and it's all confusing to understand why it'd work with a newline sequence but not with `\r`.

I am posting the sample code below, can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<chrono>
#include<thread>

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i<= 100; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "\r" << i;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(rand()%3));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am kinda new to this topic and after some digging I found out that I am messing with the threads. But still not sure why this behavior is happening.

Comment: Can you get away with just flushing the stream? cout is buffered. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22026751/c-force-stdcout-flush-print-to-screen

Comment: The program is not frozen. If you set a breakpoint, you'll see that the `std::cout << "\r" << i;` does run every few seconds. The problem is that you're not flushing the output, so the results are still in the buffer waiting to be printed. It works with `\n` because there is an automatic flush when a `\n` is printed. But `\r` does not have this special property.

Comment: Thank you so much for the replies, adding std::flush did the job but now what i am unable to understand is why is it behaving like that? i mean the first time i am calling cout with `\r` it should still print something right? but it's not printing anything at all if i am not flushing the stream. Is it something to do with the `std::this_thread::sleep_for` or just the `cout` function? Am i missing something here? Maybe an execution chart or something similar would be useful or some further elaboration on the topic. and thanks again for figuring this out for me. :)

Comment: [What is meant by stream buffering?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23298717/2752075)

Comment: @RaymondChen Please move your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine on my machine (Windows 10):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>


int main( )
{
    std::srand( std::time( 0 ) );

    for ( std::size_t i { }; i < 100; ++i )
    {
        std::cout << '\r' << i;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds( std::rand( ) % 3 ) );
    }
}
```

I suggest that you write `'\r'` instead of `"\r"` cause here you only want to print `\r` character and `"\r"` actually prints two characters (`\r` and `\0`).
Also, it's better to seed `rand` using `srand` before calling it.

However, it may not work as expected in some environments so you may need to flush the output sequence like below:

```
std::cout << '\r' << i << std::flush;
```

or like this:

```
std::cout << '\r' << i;
std::cout.flush( );
```

These are equivalent.

For more info about `flush` see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush).

Comment: Even this one is not working without flushing the `cout`. I even tried it just now on some online compilers as well as on linux g++. As soon as I add the `std::flush` it works fine otherwise it stops. The execution flow of the program is confusing me now. Also what you said about seeding using `srand` I'll surely try it out :) It's a good advice.

Comment: @Jiaar Which line did you add `std::flush` to?

Comment: Instead of `std::cout << '\r' << i;` in for loop, I used `std::cout << '\r' << i << std::flush;` and it started working as expected. I figured that'd be the right place to add it as Its the same `cout` in which I was using `\n` i.e. I was using `std::cout << '\n' << i;` and it was all working fine but I was getting new line and that was not intended for me.

Comment: @Jiaar See the updated answer.

Comment: `"\r" actually prints two characters (\r and \0)` is false. `std::cout << '\r'` and `std::cout << "\r"` do exactly the same thing.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. "\r" is a buffer that contains two characters. I may be wrong on the printing side of it though.

Comment: *"\r" is a buffer that contains two characters* Indeed, it is. *I may be wrong on the printing side of it though* Indeed, you are.