# C++ why ofstream pointing to file not populated?

Tags: c++

Here's the code found in cpp preference website.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
 
int main()
{
    std::ofstream os("test.txt");
    std::ifstream is("test.txt");
    std::string value("0");
 
    os << "Hello"; // clause 1
    is >> value;// clause 2
 
    std::cout << "Result before tie(): " << std::quoted(value) << "\n";
    is.clear();
    is.tie(&os);
 
    is >> value;
 
    std::cout << "Result after tie(): " << std::quoted(value) << "\n";
}
```

Results:
Result before tie(): "0"
Result after tie(): "Hello"

Question:
I did a breakpoint at clause 2 and noticed file test.txt not populated with "hello".

Why?

Thx

Comment: Buffering.  The runtime does not know that `is` and `os` are the same file.  The data you wrote is sitting in the `os` buffer, waiting for more data so it can be flushed to disk.  Put simply, "don't do that".  Don't try to read and write the same file from two handles at the same time.

Comment: Reading and writing the same file with two separate streams is tricky. They won't know what the other stream is doing. Say you write to stream one. The data you wrote is probably sitting in a buffer somewhere waiting for a more efficient time to actually write the data to the file.

Comment: I don't see anything specific to C++20, so tag removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your write to `os` is [buffered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298717/what-is-meant-by-stream-buffering) and not flushed to the disk immediately. Thus, your first read attempt from `is` doesn't "see" the data.

So, why the `tie()` call resolves this? According to [documentation of `basic_ios::tie()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/tie):

> A tied stream is an output stream which is synchronized with the sequence controlled by the stream buffer (`rdbuf()`), that is, **`flush()` is called on the tied stream before any input/output operation on `*this`**.

So in our case, with the `is.tie(&os)` call, `is` is the "`*this`" and `os` is the "`tied stream`". Thus, this statement instructs the standard library to automatically call `os.flush()` before each input operation on `is`.

Accordingly, on your second read from `is`, `os.flush()` which writes the data to the disk, is first called implicitly by the standard library, and that makes the data available for the input stream to read.

You can achieve the same result and receive the data on the first read by manually adding `os.flush()` between clauses 1 & 2 ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Mj1szq166)):

```
    os << "Hello"; // clause 1
    os.flush();
    is >> value;   // clause 2, value is "Hello" now!
```

But I should note, that as people mentioned in comments, all this is tricky and can easily lead to hard to grasp code. Thus, you should generally avoid reading and writing from the same file using different handles simultaneously, unless it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: On this "is.tie(&os)", according to cpp  preference tied stream is the output stream. So I presume it's referring to "os"?

Comment: @yapkm01 Yes. Thanks for the feedback! I reformulated, it is more clear now?